# How to make the buttons organized when the page is minimized?

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with my page when its minimized, the buttons are not unorganized

[image]

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-if="PlacesOfInterest.length > 0" role="row" class="text-center" ng-repeat="row in PlacesOfInterest | filter: search  | limitTo: limit as filterPlaces " ng-cloak>
        <td style="vertical-align:middle"><span class="" ng-bind="row.PlaceName"></span></td>
        {{row.PlaceName}}
        <td><img ng-if="row.PlacePhotos.length > 0" src="{{row.PlacePhotos[0].URL}}" alt="No Image" style="height:150px; width:100%"/></td>
        <td>
            <span ng-init="max = 200" ng-bind="row.PlaceDescription.slice(0,max)"></span>
            <a ng-show="row.PlaceDescription.length > 200 && max == 200" ng-click="max = 10000">... <span class="more-less"> more</span></a>
            <a class="more-less" ng-show="max > 200" ng-click="max = 200"> less</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-modify-places btn-min-width">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default-places btn-min-width">Specialities</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-delete-places btn-min-width">Delete</a>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I expect like this same as my page when it maximized
[image]

Comment: You may want to use media queries and flexbox for your solution. Like @kieber  said we need to see your CSS to provide a solution. We can only guess until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust content in a responsive way you can use css " @media ( )" it allows you to set specific css rules to the  page based on its size, this code below for example apply the css when the size was in 800px or less

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
div a { width: 150px; clear:both;}
}
```

This code is just a example, if you want, share your css that I'll show the adjust in your own code
there is alot of possibilities with @media see more here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use css flexbox to achieve this. If you are using bootstrap, its `d-flex`.

```css
.btn {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745;
  padding: .25rem .5rem;
  border-radius: .2rem;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.mr-1 {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-if="PlacesOfInterest.length > 0" role="row" class="text-center" ng-repeat="row in PlacesOfInterest | filter: search  | limitTo: limit as filterPlaces " ng-cloak>
      <td style="vertical-align:middle"><span class="" ng-bind="row.PlaceName"></span></td>
      {{row.PlaceName}}
      <td><img ng-if="row.PlacePhotos.length > 0" src="{{row.PlacePhotos[0].URL}}" alt="No Image" style="height:150px; width:100%" /></td>
      <td>
        <span ng-init="max = 200" ng-bind="row.PlaceDescription.slice(0,max)"></span>
        <a ng-show="row.PlaceDescription.length > 200 && max == 200" ng-click="max = 10000">... <span class="more-less"> more</span></a>
        <a class="more-less" ng-show="max > 200" ng-click="max = 200"> less</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="d-flex">
          <a class="btn btn-sm mr-1 btn-modify-places btn-min-width">Edit</a>
          <a class="btn btn-sm mr-1 btn-default-places btn-min-width">Specialities</a>
          <a class="btn btn-sm btn-delete-places btn-min-width">Delete</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```